# app maker libraries/ ArrayLib

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries, google-sheets-api, google-app-maker

I'm working on transforming an app from google sheet to appmaker , and I needed to add the arraylib library , the only thing that app maker doesn't recognize the ID of the library ,"1r9wNWbta3ebuYL4ENAdIp4UYKmyNiWf1AqsXYzfXduRHhTZEeTxS9MhZ", then I decided to creat my own script for the library , the thing is I couldn't find a script for the late version where they added the 'filterByValue' function , so any one can help please ? 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to open latest libraries sources by opening link in the following format:

`https://script.google.com/a/<HereGoesYourDomain(example.com)>/d/1r9wNWbta3ebuYL4ENAdIp4UYKmyNiWf1AqsXYzfXduRHhTZEeTxS9MhZ/edit`

When I click this dummy link: https://script.google.com/a/example.com/d/1r9wNWbta3ebuYL4ENAdIp4UYKmyNiWf1AqsXYzfXduRHhTZEeTxS9MhZ/edit Apps Script redirects me to the library's sources and adjusts the URL.